# Bubble sort not working

Tags: python, bubble-sort

This is my bubble sort in python put I cannot seem to find the problem.

I am looking to start creating more complex sorting algorithms, but I must first understand why my bubble sort is not functioning.

The assert is inserted to crash the program if it does not sort it correctly (which has happened every time I have run it (including debugging)

```
N=5000
#function to sort a list
def bubble_sort(numbers):
    to_go = len(list_n)
    while to_go != 0:
        newn = 0
        for i in range(1, to_go):
            if list_n[i-1] > list_n[i]:
                swap(i-1, i)
                newn = i
        to_go = newn
def swap(item_1, item_2):
    list_n[item_1], list_n[item_2] = list_n[item_2], list_n[item_1]

list_n = []
for e in range(0,N):
    list_n.append(random.randint(1,N-1))
copy = list_n[:]
#time the sorting routine
t1 = time.clock()
bubble_sort(copy)
t2 = time.clock()
#make sure the list was sorted correctly
list_n.sort()
assert(list_n==copy) 
#print how long the function took to do the sort
print 'mySort took', t2-t1, 'seconds.'
```

Comment: You probably meant to sort copy with `.sort()` instead of sorting `list_n` twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is basically that you pass the list to sort as `numbers` to the `bubble_sort` function, but inside the function, you never use that parameter.

You should replace all occurrences of `list_n` with `numbers` in `bubble_sort`, and also pass that as an additional parameter to the `swap` function, so that you're actually swapping the numbers in the list you're working on instead of the global variable `list_n`.

Comment: I am only slightly confused, what is 'that' as in the parameter that I should pass in the swap function. @olemoritz

Comment: Thanks I figured it out